# Can I initialize mangled names with metaclass in Python and is it safe?

Tags: python, metaclass

Can I initialize mangled names with metaclass and is it safe?

```
class MetaA(type):
  def __new__(metaCls, name, bases, clsDict):
    clsDict['_%s__counter' % name] = 0
    return super(MetaA, metaCls).__new__(metaCls, name, bases, clsDict)

class A(object):
  __metaclass__ = MetaA
```

I searched and not found clear explanation. I  using often mangled names but rarely metaclass and not sure it such code if valid `'_%s__%s' % (className, attrName)` - it works but maybe is not compatible.

Comment: @Blckknght metaclass is like factory for classes so you can create many classes with use metaclass and not repeat code or control code mirroring so it is good pattern to avoid errors but it is not need often. You can not achieve with OOD some aspects like separate initialization class variables per class to not share it - it is impossible with inheritance or need add some code per each class to reinitialize some shared variable to make it not shared (i.e. threading locks to avoid deadlock).

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is legal, and more or less safe (as safe as it ever is to access attributes who's names imply they are intended to be private). It may not be a good idea though, from a design perspective.

The question is, why are you using mangled names in the first place? If the attribute is intended to be accessed from multiple classes (including accesses by the class and its metaclass), you probably should use an unmangled attribute name instead.

If you often find yourself needing to work around the mangling of an attribute, you're probably overusing mangled names. Use a single leading underscore to suggest that a name is "private" (or at least, not part a class's stable, public API).

Only a few classes ever need mangled names, usually because you want their attribute namespace needs to be kept "clean" for some reason. For instance, a proxy class may want its attribute namespace to work as if it was as a duplicate of a target objcecte. Using mangled names can help prevent the proxy's instance variables from shadowing any of the target's attributes.

Comment: I am using mangled names more often than _names since it forces clean code - you can not use them at all. Meta class is not same like inherited class it is not comparable since distance to class is different and usage is different - it is too much differences to say that is the same. Consider simple example mangled variables with thread locking. Should it be visible - no? Must be visible in meta class - yes? Can be initialized by class - no? Can be initialized with object instance - no/yes but it waste of memory? Can be initialized by metaclass - yes?

Comment: BTW my code style can be improved but it is good enough to write very complex programs i.e. 500k line of code without tons of bugs.

Comment: If you put the full implementation of some behavior in a metaclass, using mangled names would make sense *if you let the metaclass do the mangling under its own name* (that is, just use `__attr` in the metaclass code). Otherwise I still think it would be better to go for an ordinary name, rather than manually performing the mangling in the metaclass. But hey, good design is largely a matter of opinion. As I said in the first paragraph of my answer, it's legal to undo mangling, if you want. If you feel it is worth while to use mangling, I'm sure you can make it work for your projects.

Comment: Yeah, good design depend on experience in composition and balance but is also subjective to someone perception - as I see I can do manual mangling to hide some details :)